# Virtual Host don't redirect properly with CakePHP and MAMP

Tags: cakephp, mamp, virtualhost

I'm developing a web with cakePHP (using MAMP as localhost) and I just configured a virtual hosts to the root of my project.

My `/etc/hosts` is

```
127.0.0.1 localhost
127.0.0.1 altair.loc
```

And my `httpd.conf`

```
NameVirtualHost *
<VirtualHost *>
    DocumentRoot "/Volumes/Macintosh HD/Users/robotThree/www/"
    ServerName localhost
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *>
    DocumentRoot "/Volumes/Macintosh HD/Users/robotThree/www/ALTAIR/altair/"
    ServerName altair.loc
</VirtualHost>
```

With this I can access to my project typing `http://altair.loc` and all controllers and actions works perfectly (i.e. `http://altair.loc/controller/action`).

The problem is that all files accessed statically fails. For example `http://altair.loc/css/main.css` fails, but it works if I type `http://altair.loc/ALTAIR/altair/css/main.css`, as if the virtual host wasn't configured.

Do you know what could be happening?
Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved. In `httpd.conf` is necessary to check that Override is for all, it was an `.htaccess` and `mod_rewrite` issue:

```
<Directory />
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
</Directory>
```

Comment: you should also always route down to webroot: `DocumentRoot "/.../www/ALTAIR/altair/webroot/"`

Comment: There are .htaccess files in ALTAIR and altair to redirect to webroot. It dosen't like me but is the way that proposes cakephp.

Comment: nope, its not. they are only there if you don't use virtual hosts (which is the default, of course). if you do, you don't need them at all (except maybe for the one in webroot - which could also be added to the vhost directive right away, though). unnecessary overhead to call another htaccess file.

Comment: I am using virtual hosts to have multiple sites under one MAMP install and this change fixed all my routing issues. Thanks.